# how to suspend/restart processes in C (linux)

Tags: c, system, process, suspend

Hi I have to write 2 fonctions for system calls that will manage the execution of task in an operating system. I couldn't find a way to suspend/restart processes. I have found a list of signals and I know the kill function and here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

typedef struct File
{
  int pid;
  struct File *pids;
} *file;

file file1 = NULL;

//this fonction is to suspend a process using its pid number
int V(int pid_num)
{
  //does the kill fonction just kill the process or will it take into account the signal argument?
  kill(pid_num, SIGSTOP);
  file1 = ajouter(file1, pid_num);
  return 0;
}

//this is to restart the process
int C()
{
  if (file1 != NULL)
  {
    //I know the kill fonction is not the right one but I just don't know any other to take as argument the pid of a process to restart it
    kill(file1->pid, SIGCONT);
  }
  return 0;
}

//this fontion adds pid number to our structure
file ajouter(file file_n, int pid)
{
  file nouveau = malloc(sizeof(file));
  nouveau->pid = pid;
  nouveau->pids = file_n;
  return nouveau;
}
```

remark: this code is not supposed to really work it's just a little simulation
thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Why do you use a global `file1` and give it as a parameter to `ajouter` ? this is useless, chose between global or not but do not mix.

Also, prefer `next` instead of `pids` as this is a chained list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kill` will not just 'kill' the process whose ID you gave it. It sends the signal you give it.

Answer (score 10):

Send a process `SIGSTOP` to pause it and `SIGCONT` to resume it.

These signals are used to implement shell job control and because of that they can't be caught, blocked or ignored (otherwise an application could defy job control).